# Хочу использовать import или require в обычном JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Сейчас я пишу javascript код, используя классы. Пример кода:

```
class User {
    static addUser(data) {
    /** делаю сохранение **/
    }
}
```

Потом вешаю на `onclick` нужное событие. Меня все устраивает, но в одном файле может быть много таких классов и сложно становится их искать.

Хотел сделать через модули. Создал папку `js/modules`. В папке создал файл UserModule.js Пример:

```
class User {
    static addUser(data) {
    /** делаю сохранение **/
    }
}

module.exports = User
```

В файле `js/app.js` делаю

```
const User = require('./modules/User')
```

Браузер говорит

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Читаю, что нету поддержки. Пробовал сделать через `require.js` - не вышло, ошибки.

И вот сам вопрос: есть какие то "препроцессоры", как sass для css или как правильно это сделать?

P.S. В проекте использую Jquery

Comment: Ну так используйте import, для него не нужно никаких препроцессоров

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/modules